# Fall creators update performance issues

Tags: c#, performance, windows-10, log4net

After the recent Windows 10 Update (Fall Creators Update) the performance of our .NET c# 4.0 application had decreased a lot. I think there are various issues and one of them is log4net (or disk IO).

Our application is very complex (various WCF applications and a ASPNET MVC 3.0 app) and in development there are a lot of log4net traces. Loading the first page in startup lasts 4 or 5 minutes and before the updates lasts a minute, If I deactivate log4net the performance.

I've done a test with two cloned virtual machines, logging after a regex operation, and the diferrences are significant.

The code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Info("Log4net1");

        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            DoTheThing();
        }


        TimeSpan elapsedTime = DateTime.Now - start;
        Log.DebugFormat("TOTAL Elapsed time: {0}", elapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void DoTheThing()
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        Regex.Replace(TEXT, " nec ", m =>
        {
            return " (word nec) ";
        });
        TimeSpan elapsedTime = DateTime.Now - start;
        Log.DebugFormat("Elapsed time: {0}", elapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds);
    }
```

I've done tests with log4net 1.2.1 and 2.0.8:

average beforeUpdate -> TOTAL Elapsed time: 600ms

average afterUpdate -> TOTAL Elapsed time: 1000ms

It's a very important issue for us, and I haven't found any info on the net.

-- UPDATE --

I've found another (unanswered) thread on stackoverflow:
[log4net became very slow with caller location information after Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (1709)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760546/log4net-became-very-slow-with-caller-location-information-after-windows-10-fall)

I've ran a disk benchmark on both environments and there's no significant differences on read/write rates. 
I've tested the application disabling completely log4net (log4net threshold="OFF") and now the timings are very similar, so, as @DalmTo comments, there a lot of possibilities that it would be due to log4net, I'll try to put an issue there, although there is already a related microsoft issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3143189/after-installing-windows-10-1709-update-creating-a-stacktrace-class-has-become-a-magnitude-slower

Comment: I think you should consider posting an issue to log4net

Comment: Have you gone through the release notes to see what changes have been made? Maybe you can get some idea about what to look for.

Comment: Could the slowdown be related to Meltdown/Spectre patches?

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, but I really think it's not directly its responsability, I'll wait for a more generic response...

Comment: @Fildor Yes, but I haven't found any relevant info about that.

Comment: @sgmoore I thought that too. The problem is that FCU was released before Meltdown/Spectre were famous, and I've no evidence that FCU included fixes on those vulnerabilities. I'm afraid that it could go worse when I install those patches!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could be hit by this issue:

> Starting in October 2017, after you upgrade to Windows 10 Version 1709
>   or .NET Framework 4.7.1, you notice a significant decrease in
>   performance when you run .NET Framework applications that use the
>   System.Diagnostics.StackFrame class.
>
> Applications typically rely on StackFrame when they throw .NET
>   exceptions. If this occurs at a high rate (more than 10 incidents per
>   second), applications can slow down significantly (tenfold) and run
>   noticeably slower than before.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057154/performance-of-system-diagnostics-stackframe-degrades-in-windows-10-17

> The .NET Framework 4.7.1 added support for detecting and parsing the
>   Portable PDB file format to show file and line number information in
>   stack traces. As part of this change, each function in a stack trace
>   has its defining module checked to determine if that module uses the
>   Portable PDB format.
>
> Due to some differences in the internal caching
>   policy, the runtime spends far more time searching for Portable PDBs
>   than previous .NET Framework versions spent searching for classic
>   Windows PDBs. This causes formatted stack traces to be produced more
>   slowly than before.

https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net471/KnownIssues/517815-BCL%20Applications%20making%20heavy%20use%20of%20System.Diagnostics.StackTrace%20might%20run%20more%20slowly%20on%20.NET%204.7.1.md

Installing the latest .NET 4.7.1 Reliability Update (KB4054856) should resolve this.

- Windows 10 Fall Creators needs KB4058258 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4058258

> The following fixes are included:
>   Applications making heavy use of System.Diagnostics.StackTrace or Exception.StackTrace might run more slowly on the .NET Framework 4.7.1.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/01/09/net-framework-4-7-1-is-available-on-windows-update-wsus-and-mu-catalog/

Comment: This confirms my bias that Exceptions should be Exceptional and are expensive (this is also borne out from other sources).

Comment: @Mgetz log4net can be configured to uses the StackTrace-class for capturing the callsite (class + method + etc.). Which will probably receive a performance hit (though already expensive).

Comment: I'm using .Net Framework 4.0, and I'm not ready to migrate to 4.7.1 in short term. @RolfKristensen do you know if there's another way to configure log4net to reduce that performance hit?

Comment: @Marc Think you can fix it by just installing the mentioned KB4054856 on the Windows10-machines. Changing log4net capture sounds like a different question, but you can try and configure the `<Fix value="772"/>` for the appender (See also https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Core_FixFlags.htm )

Comment: @Marc: _"I'm using .Net Framework 4.0"_ -- then the issue described above can't be what's causing your apparent problem, as the above problem only appears in 4.7.1, before the also-mentioned Reliability Update.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You're right! It's not my issue, but it's an interesting response for other with a similar problem. I think that I've the same problem but on .NetFramework 4.0.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The support article is not clear. It says after you upgrade to Windows 10 Version 1709 **OR** .NET Framework 4.7.1, (which implies one thing) but the workarounds seem to be either to downgrade the Windows **OR** Framework version (which implies another thing). But if the issue only applies to Framework 4.7.1 then why mention Windows 10 Version 1709 as a special case at all).

Comment: Not working at Microsoft, so maybe things are different now. But last time I checked, then Net4-version-updates works as CLR replacement ( https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Mar/13/NET-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-NET-40 ). Older versions of net4 are simulated using shims (to ensure old behavior stays), but sometimes the simulation fails.

Comment: With the last update of the KB, I've updated my Windows and that's solved: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057154/performance-of-system-diagnostics-stackframe-degrades-in-windows-10-17 --> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4058258